# How to Create multiple Values from textEditingController

Tags: flutter, texteditingcontroller

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i92XW.png

I couldn't find something related and I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this or if should I take a different approach.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this work using this package

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead

You can get suggestions, on search and also, you can use
flutter chip widget to show selection like above.

https://material.io/components/chips/flutter

I have done this method to achieve above scenario you mentioned.